# Unable to add a script button as a left sidebar new tool item in Tabletop Simulator

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

I am preparing a mod for a tabletop simulator game, and I will be using clickable buttons as there are many options and different setups depending on the number of players that come and how they want to play the game. However, the game is extensive in the number of pieces in the table, so I was trying to add the buttons (that run the setup scripts) as left sidebar tool add-ons so we didn't stretch the table further to the sides to house the setup buttons.

I have looked through the app documentation and I found no way to script-force the buttons into left sidebar tool icons. All I could find was to add some dropdown menus by using XML in the CUSTOM UI but nothing specific that would create a left sidebar new buttons and items.

Is there something I missed and there is a possibility to do it?

Thanks in advance

Best regards
Luis Lima

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this workshop
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1393821479

in it there's a section of coding under the UI tab that if you modify it then the created floating button can be moved over to the left side. I believe with this you could create your own drop down menus as well. Note I did edit the below line of coding to put the button on the left below the rest of the menu buttons. Hope this helps you achieve what you want.

```
    id="rollerLayout"
    height="280"
    width="80"
    allowDragging="true"
    returnToOriginalPositionWhenReleased="false"
    rectAlignment="UpperLeft"
    offsetXY="00 -525"
    >
```